get element to appear at the end of a line in reactjs, regardless of screen size
So i have this element which flips words in a fixed interval.
         <div
            className="inline-block flex justify-center items-center before:content-['lore_ipsum_dolor_lore_ipsum_dolor']  drop-shadow-[0_3px_3px_rgba(0,0,0,1)] text-2xl md:text-3xl mb-4"
          >
            <FlipWords words={["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]} />
          </div>

it renders ok on a medium and large screen

but when the screen gets mobile sized...

I would want the "words" to appear here in this case:

So it shouldn't matter the screen size, when that element's flex works its math based on container size, it should still stay alongside the last word in the phrase, how should i do that?
FlipWords implementation
https://ui.aceternity.com/components/flip-words

Can you add your flip words implementation ?

https://ui.aceternity.com/components/flip-words

I believe it is due to flex. Can you remove the flex property and see if it works ?

This is because the :before element and the flipper are two separate flex items to be placed side by side.
Since you're using React, the easiest solution is to move your :before contents ("lore ipsum dolor...") under a wrapper to be wrapped together with the flipped words.
Finally, if you want to center your text after they wrap, justify-center is not enough. text-center is also needed.
<div className="inline-block flex justify-center text-center items-center drop-shadow-[0_3px_3px_rgba(0,0,0,1)] text-2xl md:text-3xl mb-4">
  <div>
    lore ipsum dolor lore ipsum_dolor
    <FlipWords words={["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]} />
  </div>
</div>


One pure CSS solution idea is to use display: contents (contents in Tailwind) on :before and the wrapper of the flipped words. This makes them not produce a specific box by themselves so their child/pseudo boxes will be placed directly together. **This assumes the words in the <FlipWords> component are not nested under other wrappers, which isn't your case.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="inline-block flex justify-center text-center items-center before:contents before:content-['lore_ipsum_dolor_lore_ipsum_dolor']  drop-shadow-[0_3px_3px_rgba(0,0,0,1)] text-2xl md:text-3xl mb-4">
  <div class="contents whitespace-pre"> word1</div><!--<FlipWords>-->
</div>




here is the flipwords implementation, it contains wrappers for the words
https://ui.aceternity.com/components/flip-words

Answer updated. In this case, I'll say just group the content and FlipWords into a wrapper so that they won't be separated into two flex items.
